# SQL server Select Distinct with Order By

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, case, distinct

I am not very known to DB query but getting error

> "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is
>   specified."

with below query. I searched on google and found that order by need to group if using Distinct but still not able to get it. Can anyone help me out.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       P1.*
FROM T_PRD P1
     LEFT JOIN T_PRD P2 ON P1.baseprdid = P2.prdid
     INNER JOIN T_PRD_NM_VENDOR prdNmVendor ON P1.prdId = prdNmVendor.prdId
     INNER JOIN T_VENDOR_NM vendorNM ON prdNmVendor.vendorNMId = vendorNM.vendorNMId
     INNER JOIN T_NM nm ON vendorNM.NMId = nm.NMId
     INNER JOIN T_PRD_VENDOR prdVendor ON prdVendor.PRDId = P1.PRDId
     INNER JOIN T_VENDOR vendor ON prdVendor.vendorId = vendor.vendorId
     INNER JOIN T_CSTMR_PRD_REF custPrd ON custPrd.ProductId = P1.PRDId
     INNER JOIN T_CSTMR cstmr ON custPrd.ChennelCstrId = cstmr.cstmrid
WHERE 1 = 1
      AND P1.Lifecycle = 2
      AND P1.AutoCreated = 0
      AND vendor.vendorId = 1
      AND P1.VendorEnfId = 1
      AND cstmr.cstmrid = 2008
ORDER BY CASE
             WHEN P1.BASEPRDID = 0
             THEN P1.PRDNAME
             ELSE P2.PRDNAME
         END ASC, 
         BASEPRDID;
```

Comment: Can you please try after adding P2.PRDNAME and BASEPRDID in the SELECT part?

Comment: What's your DBMS ..?

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server

Answer (score 1):

Your ORDER BY depends on  expression which  is missing from `SELECT DISTINCT` list . Add it

```
 SELECT DISTINCT  P1.*
        ,CASE
             WHEN P1.BASEPRDID = 0
             THEN P1.PRDNAME
             ELSE P2.PRDNAME
         END col
```